# Deleting lines of a series of ASCII (.csv) files having a certain row number

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

I have a series of 297 directories named as "dir000', 'dir001' and so on, each of which contains a text file called "config", which is a csv file with 3 columns and 256 rows. I have generated 25 random numbers in the range 1 to 256, and from all these files in each directory, I am required to remove those exact 25 rows. For instance, if my generator gave me a series of random numbers `a = [145,11,140,119,183,178,225,131,1,65,213,115,207,41,194,221,10,205,6,57,224,108,44,85,211]`, I want to delete exactly these rows from each of the ASCII files("config") in each directory. Can anyone let me know how this can be achieved using command line? I am using Ubuntu 16.04 distribution.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2112496/3342816

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following uses perl's `-i` option for in-place editing of the input files.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -i

use strict;

# Parse array of random numbers from the first argument.
my $arg1 = shift;
# remove [, ], and any whitespace.
$arg1 =~ s/\[|\]|\s+//g;

# split $arg1 on commas, build an associative array 
# (aka "hash") called %a to hold the numbers.
# The hash keys are the line numbers, and the value for 
# each key is just "1" - it doesn't matter what the
# value is, the only thing that matters is whether the
# key exists in the hash.
my %a;
map $a{$_} = 1, split(/,/, $arg1);

# Loop over each input file.
while (<>) {
  # Print each line unless the current line number $. is in %a.
  print unless defined $a{$.};

  # reset $. at the end of each file.
  close(ARGV) if eof;
}
```

Save it as, e.g., `delete-lines.pl` and make it executable with `chmod +x delete-lines.pl`, and run it like:

```
$ a="[145,11,140,119,183,178,225,131,1,65,213,115,207,41,194,221,10,205,6,57,224,108,44,85,211]"
$ ./delete-lines.pl "$a" textfile*.txt
```

If `textfile1.txt`, `textfile2.txt`, `textfile3.txt` all contain the following **before** execution:

```
I have a series of 297 directories named as "dir000', 'dir001' and so on, each
of which contains a text file called "config", which is a csv file with 3
columns and 256 rows.

I have generated 25 random numbers in the range 1 to 256, and from all these
files in each directory, I am required to remove those exact 25 rows.

For instance, if my generator gave me a series of random numbers a =
[145,11,140,119,183,178,225,131,1,65,213,115,207,41,194,221,10,205,6,57,224,10
8,44,85,211], I want to delete exactly these rows from each of the ASCII
files("config") in each directory.

Can anyone let me know how this can be achieved using command line? I am using
Ubuntu 16.04 distribution.
```

Then they will all contain this **after** execution:

```
of which contains a text file called "config", which is a csv file with 3
columns and 256 rows.

I have generated 25 random numbers in the range 1 to 256, and from all these

For instance, if my generator gave me a series of random numbers a =
[145,11,140,119,183,178,225,131,1,65,213,115,207,41,194,221,10,205,6,57,224,10

Can anyone let me know how this can be achieved using command line? I am using
Ubuntu 16.04 distribution.
```

i.e. lines **1**, **6**, **10**, and **11** have been deleted from each of them - because those are the only line numbers in the files that are in the array of random numbers.

BTW, the `%a` hash contains the following:

```
{
    1 => 1,   6 => 1,  10 => 1,  11 => 1,  41 => 1,
   44 => 1,  57 => 1,  65 => 1,  85 => 1, 108 => 1,
  115 => 1, 119 => 1, 131 => 1, 140 => 1, 145 => 1,
  178 => 1, 183 => 1, 194 => 1, 205 => 1, 207 => 1,
  211 => 1, 213 => 1, 221 => 1, 224 => 1, 225 => 1,
}
```

The next step is to run it on lots of files named "config" in your numbered directories:

```
find dir[0-9]*/ -type f -name config -exec ./delete-lines.pl "$a" {} +
```

This assumes that the array of random numbers is still in shell variable `$a`.  You can use another variable name if you like, or just provide it as a quoted string - as long as you provide the array as the **first** argument to the perl script (with all subsequent args being filenames), it will work.

---

If you don't want to save a stand-alone script, you can run it as a one-liner:

```bsh
$ find dir[0-9]*/ -type f -name config -exec perl -i -e \
    'map $a{$_} = 1, split(/,/, ($ARGV[0] =~ s/\[|\]| +//g, shift));
     while (<>) {print unless defined $a{$.}; close(ARGV) if eof}' \
     "$a" {} +
```

But why would you? it would just be ugly and difficult to read and edit.  Writing a temporary throwaway script in your favourite editor is easier and more convenient than trying to edit and debug a script on the shell command line.